# Fixie: Static IP Address with Heroku

Tags: heroku, scrapy

I have a web scraping app hosted by heroku. I always get 403 errors on heroku, but page works fine if I run the code locally. I assume this error is due to Heroku dynamic ip. I installed Fixie and I want the spider to send requests from a static address. How to do it?

spider:

```
yield scrapy.Request('https://www.ratemds.com/best-doctors/?specialty=%s' % specialty, callback=self.profile_link, 
                                    headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.50747 OPRGX/60.0.3255.50747"},
                                    meta={"proxy": "http://fixie:XkWpxhGyIgZq454@velodrome.usefixie.com:80"})
```

Heroku CLI:

```
E:\Python\heroku3>heroku config:get FIXIE_URL
http://fixie:XkWpxhGyIgZq454@velodrome.usefixie.com:80
```

Comment: "I assume this error is due to Heroku dynamic ip"—what makes you think this? It's more likely to be the Heroku / AWS _block_ of IPs that can be used.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: We still don't have enough information to know what the problem is. If it's the IP range as I suggested, the only solution is to host elsewhere. But that might not fix it: if the site being scraped is blocking Heroku / AWS ranges it's probably blocking most other big hosts, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the site is probably blocking your IP, you can bypass that by using a proxie (just like you configured fixie).

Fixie is setting up a proxy on top of your application, so you can visit other sites with an static IP, which means that you are visiting a site with the same IP every time. It is very normal for (some) sites to block an IP that is visiting them "irregularly", as they suspect they are bots.

A solution for the previous problem is for your crawler to use several proxies randomly for requests to those sites, or to use a proxy rotator service that will do that automatically for you, with you just configuring one proxy (just like you did with fixie).

Another thing that I noticed is that the site you shared cannot be accessed with IPs outside the US (I wasn't able to enter, not after using a US VPN), so make sure, first that Fixie is giving you a US static IP. If you are sure Fixie is doing that, then there is a high chance you'll have to use a proxy rotator service, also make sure they are giving you US proxies when you request them.